# Нужно отключить возможность ввода более одного "-" символа

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть данное регулярное выражение `/^[-0-9\b]+(\.\d{0,2})?$/` для валидации положительных и отрицательных чисел

Он отлично работает и для положительных и для отрицательных(например `-12.34`), но пользователь может несколько раз ввести знак минуса(пример: `-12-3-4.12`).

Как я могу переписать вышеупомянутый код, чтобы можно было вводить только один минус и только в начале строки?

Comment: Попробуйте `/^-?\d*\.?\d{0,2}$/`.

Comment: попробовал, заработало. Спасибо вам большое. Оформите ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в коде, похоже, используется такой метод, который использует проверку с регулярным выражением для валидации по мере ввода символов ("live validation"). В таких случаях необходимо использовать такое выражение, которое состоит из необязательных шаблонов, т.е. таких, которые могут находить пустую строку.

```
/^(-(?!\.))?\d*\.?\d{0,2}$/
```

Это выражение находит

- `^` - начало строки
- `(-(?!\.))?`  - необязательный символ `-`, после которого не должно быть симола `.`
- `\d*` - ноль и  более цифр
- `\.?` - ноль или одна точка
- `\d{0,2}` - 0, 1 или 2 цифры
- `$` - конец строки.

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/BDptHR/2).

Comment: `-.` - такое тоже не должно проходить.

Comment: @UModeL Нет проблем. Добавьте блок преварительного просмотра вперёд и оберните `-` в опциональную подмаску.

Comment: @WiktorStribiew: мне то зачем оборачивать? Я не автор вопроса :) Просто подсказал, что есть малюсенький недочёт.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/BDptHR/4 в конце разные вариации. Проходят `-` `.` `-0` `0.` `-0.`

Comment: @DiD `-` - первый в строке, он и должен "проходить". Вы и UModel исходите из того, что это выражение для финальной валидации, а я исхожу из того, что это выражение нужно для валидации при вводе каждого символа из разрешённой последовательности. Если mix добавит свой код в вопрос, можно будет протестировать и увидеть, как всё работает, или даже добавить onsubmit validation типа `pattern="\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?"`.